# Bash/Shell: How to remove duplicates from csv file by columns?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, csv, uniq

I have a csv separated with `;`. I need to remove lines where content of 2nd and 3rd column is not unique, and deliver the material to the standard output.

Example input:

```
irrelevant;data1;data2;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data3;data4;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data5;data6;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data7;data8;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data1;data2;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data9;data0;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data1;data2;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data3;data4;irrelevant;irrelevant
```

Desired output

```
irrelevant;data5;data6;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data7;data8;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data9;data0;irrelevant;irrelevant
```

I have found solutions where only first line is printed to the output:

```
sort -u -t ";" -k2,1 file
```

but this is not enough.

I have tried to use `uniq -u` but I can't find a way to check only a few columns.

Comment: in all the lines there isn't an unique value in the 2nd and 3rd columns.

Comment: I agree with @jaypal, that question is about finding unique records only.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: OP wants to list those records where `col2, col3` appear only once in whole file.

Comment: Yes, @anubhava is right. Storing the material in some temporary template seems to be the only way. It seems both awk and perl solutions are very similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '!seen[$2,$3]++{data[$2,$3]=$0}
      END{for (i in seen) if (seen[i]==1) print data[i]}' file
irrelevant;data5;data6;irrelevant;irrelevant
irrelevant;data7;data8;irrelevant;irrelevant
irrelevant;data9;data0;irrelevant;irrelevant
```

**Explanation:** If `$2,$3` combination doesn't exist in `seen` array then a new entry with key of `$2,$3` is stored in `data` array with whole record. Every time `$2,$3` entry is found a counter for `$2,$3` is incremented. Then in the end those entries with `counter==1` are printed.

Answer (score -1):

If order is important and if you can use `perl` then:

```
perl -F";" -lane '
    $key = @F[1,2]; 
    $uniq{$key}++ or push @rec, [$key, $_] 
}{ 
    print $_->[1] for grep { $uniq{$_->[0]} == 1 } @rec' file
irrelevant;data5;data6;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data7;data8;irrelevant;irrelevant  
irrelevant;data9;data0;irrelevant;irrelevant
```

We use column2 and column3 to create composite key. We create array of array by pushing the key and the line to array `rec` for the first occurrence of the line.

In the `END` block, we check if that occurrence is the only occurrence. If so, we go ahead and print the line.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file_input > file_output
```

This worked for me. It compares whole lines.